# libgdx - Check if body is touch

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d, touch

I have some bodies around the screen(`Ball[] balls`), and I would like to delete them when user touches them.

Also, I have an `Image` as userData of the bodies.

I dont want to make a function to all `Image`, because the balls have to be deleted in an order.

What is the best way to detect if a body is touch?

Comment: Why use a array? You might be better off using a list. Click ball -> call dispose on image -> remove from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to extend the `Image` class and add a touch listener.

Add this code into your `Image` subclass:

```
private void addTouchListener() {
    this.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            YourClassName.this.wasTouched();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where Have I call the addTouchListener() function?